# Big matrix with compile-time known size in Eigen: MatrixXd or Matrix<double, n, m>?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm using Eigen to write some C++ linear algebra code. I've got to manipulate some not-so-small matrices (greater than 4x4, but smaller than 50x50, if that matters), whose sizes are all entirely known at compile time.

I would love to benefit from the compile-time size checks that Eigen library can perform around matrix operations, which trigger an error whenever, say, a sum between different-size matrices happens in the code, however I'm also scared about the possible abuse of the stack that I could make if I don't dinamically allocate those relatively big objects. Performance concerns doesn't bother me.

The [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) has a brief paragraph about fixed and dynamic size matrices, where my previous concerns are discussed, but unfortunately there is no emphasys on the compile time checks which I would love to maintain. The documentation suggests:

> Use fixed sizes for very small sizes where you can, and use dynamic sizes for larger sizes or where you have to.

In the end, my question: is there a way in Eigen to have a dynamically allocated Matrix with compile-time known size, in a way to retain the usual compile-time checks that we have for standard fixed-size matrices?

Something like this:

```
using MyMatrix = MatrixXd<12, 15>; // Currently I can only do Matrix<double, 12, 15>
using MyVector = MatrixXd<14, 1>;
MyMatrix M;
MyVector v;
auto w = M * v; // This should trigger an INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT error
```

where `MatrixXd<n, m>` is the hypothetical dynamically allocated, compile-time known size matrix I would like to use!

Comment: Fixed-sized matrices with heap-allocated storage are indeed not supported (it could actually also be beneficial when moving or swapping matrix objects). Maybe do a feature request for that (API-wise this could be achieved by adding a flag to the `Options` template parameter)

Comment: Also, if you don't have hundreds of these matrices or working on some embedded systems, you should be fine with occupying a few KiB on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse inheritance from Eigen classes that provide Matrix-like wrappers:

1. `Eigen::Block`

   ```
   struct MatrixHelper { Eigen::MatrixXd mat; };

   template <int Rows, int Cols>
   struct CheckedDynamicMatrix
     : MatrixHelper, Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, Rows, Cols>
   {
     using Block = Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixXd, Rows, Cols>;
     CheckedDynamicMatrix() :
       MatrixHelper { Eigen::MatrixXd(Rows, Cols) },
       Block { mat.topLeftCorner<Rows, Cols>() }
     {}
   };
   ```
2. `Eigen::Map`

   ```
   template <int Rows, int Cols>
   struct CheckedDynamicMatrix
     : Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Rows, Cols>>
   {
     using Map = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Rows, Cols>>;
     std::unique_ptr<double[]> data;
     CheckedDynamicMatrix() :
       Map { nullptr },
       data { new double[Rows * Cols] }
     {
       new (static_cast<Map*>(this)) Map(data.get(), Rows, Cols);
     }
   };
   ```

For full functionality, you should also add the necessary constructor and assignment operator as described in [Eigen: Inheriting from Matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_InheritingMatrix.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can't persuade<sup>1</sup> Eigen to do both, but you can dynamically allocate a fixed-size matrix.

```
using MyMatrix = Matrix<double, 12, 15>;
using MyVector = Matrix<double, 14, 1>;
auto M = std::make_unique<MyMatrix>();
auto v = std::make_unique<MyVector>();
auto w = *M * *v; // compile time error, as desired
```

Footnote 1: There isn't documentation as to what happens if you set `MaxRows` and `MaxCols` with a fixed size `Matrix`, so you could try `Matrix<double, 12, 15, 0, Dynamic, Dynamic>` and see what happens, but beware the behaviour of that may change without warning, or could lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Passing `Dynamic` as last parameters for fixed-sized matrices will result in compilation errors: https://godbolt.org/z/VJBT6C